# FTP move files/folder on remote server in FileZilla

Tags: ftp, sftp, filezilla

I have a folder on my server that I want to move to a different location on that same server.

I see that I can move a file/folder into a sibling folder, or up one folder, by dragging it over the "folder name"/"..", respectively.

How can I move the folder to a different folder located at a far distant place in the folder tree?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the menu bar, click **View** and check **Remote directory tree** (alternatively, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>).

Go to the source folder where the subfolder you want to move is, go the destination folder and go back to the source folder.

The destination folder should still be visible in the directory tree, so you can just drag the folder you want to move and drop it into the destination folder.